# Add a background to a material icon

Tags: html, css, material-ui, material-design

I have the following material Icon code. However, I would like to add the white background to give it more contras. Any ideas how to add the background?

```
<a id="lnk_quick_print" href="javascript:;" title="Quick Print" onclick="window.print();" class="material-icons icon noQuickPrint" style="font-size:14px;margin-left: 8px;">print</a>
```

[image: Two Icon examples. Would like to implement #2]

Comment: Add a `background: white` and `border-radius: 3px` CSS property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `background-color:white` in the style

```
<a id="lnk_quick_print" href="javascript:;" title="Quick Print" onclick="window.print();" class="material-icons icon noQuickPrint" style="font-size:14px;background-color:white;margin-left: 8px;">print</a>
```

Comment: This works great. The only thing I had to add was a border-radius to round off the corners just a little.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this:

```
<a id="lnk_quick_print" href="javascript:;" title="Quick Print" onclick="window.print();" class="material-icons icon noQuickPrint" style="background: white; padding: 5px 10px; box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); border-radius: 10px; font-size:14px;margin-left: 8px;">print</a>
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution. I just tried the first one posted and it worked; So, running with that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<a id="lnk_quick_print" href="javascript:;" title="Quick Print" onclick="window.print();" class="material-icons icon noQuickPrint" style="font-size:24px;margin-left: 8px;background:white;padding:5px 6px">print</a>
```

Comment: Very similar to the others. Thank you.